# Two foster kids talk (as captives) through an air duct between their rooms?

Tags: identify-this-movie

Several years ago I remember seeing part of a movie - perhaps even a TV only movie - but I can't remember the name of it.

I think the premise was that a (married?) couple acted as temporary foster parents to two teenagers (boarding them temporarily). The foster parents were strict, quirky, OCD, and ruled the teens in an obsessive, dictator style.

Seems like for most of the day the kids were locked in their adjacent rooms, and were not supposed to make any noise or else be punished. I think they had a little desk in there and were supposed to be only studying or something like that. I think the foster parents even did things like passing the meals through a window in the door - like the teenagers were incarcerated. Not sure if I remember that part 100%.

I believe the teenage girl was there first and then the teenage boy arrives, she tries to maybe tell him about the rules to keep him out of trouble. They whisper through an air vent in the wall, and I think maybe they make an escape or something like that.

I have no idea what this movie is titled and without knowing really anything more about it I'm not having any luck with Google.

Also, for some reason this movie comes to mind when I think about the Goonies - which I haven't seen in a while, but I doubt that is the movie I'm describing...

### More Info

- Seems like this was one of those late 80's movies.
- I think the boy had dark brown hair and the girl had ligher brown hair...
- I think both of the foster parents were really thin and lanky - I think the guy reminded me of nicholas cage possibly.

Comment: Any idea what happens at the end?

Comment: @phwd - I'm not sure - I think they escape or maybe get revenge on the foster parents. I really remember this looking and feeling like an 80s movie, like with qualities of WarGames or The Goonies...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be [George's Island](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0097419/). This is a tale about two children who are put in a foster home, and then on Halloween they breakout and are rescued by their eccentric grandfather.

Comment: +1 - maybe, although I'm pretty sure the kids were teenagers... also can't find much info about this movie online. the two clips on youtube don't look that promising. the date ('89) is right! :)

Answer (score 3):

I want to say *[The People Under the Stairs](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0105121/)*, but I'm sure you would have mentioned ghoulish kids and a shotgun wielding fetishist.

Answer (score 1):

Was it Flowers in the Attic?

http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0093036/

They were locked in the attic together, so it doesn't sound exactly like this.

Comment: +1 - thanks for responding. no it wasn't that. i was trying to use google images to search for it, came across PHENOMENA which looked closer to what i remembered, but that wasn't it either. I really don't think I'm dreaming this up - at least I hope I'm not!

Answer (score 1):

Might be a reach, but is it [The Glass House](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0221218/)?

Edit:

It has a brother and sister that are put under guardianship when their parents are murdered.  Eventually they try to escape the guardians.

Comment: Please add a description on why you think this is the answer. Answers containing links only without explanation are not allowed globally on SE.

Comment: This was the first thing I thought of...

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're referring to 1992 TV movie [Child of rage](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0103955/)

Comment: Giving a little detail for the justification is better.

Comment: Apart from what Ankit has commented above, you might also hyperlink the name of the movie to IMDb or Rotten Tomatoes. It's also a good idea to give a synopsis which relates to the details mentioned in the question.